# Is there a way to run gem's rspec in project's root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

For example, I create a new rails project by `rails new test_projct`, and I include `rails-spec` and `custom_gem`(this is created by us include models and rspec test cases) into `gemfile`. If I run `rspec` in the root of project folder, I hope it could run both `test_project`'s test cases in `spec` folder and `custom_gem`'s test cases in `spec` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Running tests/specs for a gem from within a Rails app should not be necessary or useful. A gem is a discrete unit of, hopefully, tested functionality. If you are concerned about specs passing for a particular gem you should do that in isolation. For example, checkout the gem code into its own folder and run the specs for that gem in isolation. If the gem does not have specs or tests, you could write some to cover the concerns that you have and submit a patch or pull-request on the project.

Once you have the specs passing in isolation for the gem, you can include the gem in your Rails project with confidence and not need to worry about running it's specs within the project.